# Miniseries about descendant of Jack from Jack and the Beanstalk

Tags: story-identification, tv

Like I said in the question heading it revolved around a man (possibly played by Matthew Modine) in the modern age whose ancestor was the titular Jack in Jack and the Beanstalk, only from the miniseries point of view Jack was the villain who stole from and killed an innocent giant and the descendant had to atone for what his ancestor did.

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the date, this sounds like "[Jack and the Beanstalk: The Real Story](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264262/)", a two episode miniseries broadcast in 2001. It indeed starred Matthew Modine as "Jack Robinson", a descendant of the Jack of beanstalk fame, who must atone for his ancestor's mistakes and return the magical harp and the goose that lays golden eggs to their rightful owner.

Comment: I agree with Clara.  Definitely sounds like the Modine movie she indicated.